# からできる vs からできている

Tags: grammar

These were given as two example sentences on a site and I'm wondering if someone can explain the difference/which is right.

スーパーは木曜日にミルクからできている製品のセールをするよ

スーパーは木曜日にミルクからできる製品のセールをするよ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the site, Dan!

I don't know if "idiom" is the correct word, but the ...からできている is a phrase with a special meaning, in English "made (out) of ..."

I wonder if the above were example sentences, or a part of a question like "please select which one of the below alternatives is correct". Assuming the latter, the 1st one is right. (And means essentially means that dairy products are on sale on Thursdays)

But the sentence is clumsy and normally would not be used, as you realize contrasting "dairy products" with "products made out of milk". The ending よ indicates that this is probably told by a fellow consumer (and not eg printed on an advertisement). The the ending よ might best be translated as a leading "You know," or "FYI:"

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So in what situations would you want to use できる rather than できている?

Comment: If you mean with から, and when using it in the meaning of "make / made of", I can't come up with a good example of "...からできる", so the answer MAY BE that you wouldn't use it in that way. As a probably separate question, the でできている is a phrase similar to からできている, but also here, while I guess a question like "パンを作るには何が必要？"might  get an answer like "小麦や卵でできる", I think that in such case the でできる should be consider to mean the "can" in "you can make bread from wheat and eggs" (and not the "make ... from")